# Get correct pointer of argument

Tags: c, gcc, clang, callstack

I have this... weird problem and I'm desperately looking for a solution.

We have this example: (made for 32-bit systems)

```
#include <stdio.h>

//unsigned foo(unsigned arg_a, unsigned arg_b) {
unsigned foo(unsigned arg_a, ...) {
        unsigned *temp = (unsigned *)((unsigned)&arg_a + 4);
        return *temp + arg_a;
}

int main(void) {
        int i = foo(0xbe00, 0x00af);
        printf("We got a %x\n", i);
        return 0;
}
```

Function foo has 2 arguments. The goal is to "guess" the address of arg_b based on the address of the arg_a. This is based on the assumption that caller (main) will push arg_a and arg_b into the stack (so that (int)&arg_b - (int)&arg_a == 4 ).

Depending on the compiler and the optimization level, the output differs as follows:

```
 gcc -g -Wall -O0 test.c
 ./a.out 
We got a beaf
 gcc -g -Wall -O1 test.c
 ./a.out 
We got a beaf
 gcc -g -Wall -O2 test.c
 ./a.out 
We got a 80542b0
 gcc -g -Wall -O3 test.c
 ./a.out 
We got a 80542b0
 clang -g -Wall -O0 test.c
 ./a.out 
We got a 8054281
 clang -g -Wall -O1 test.c
 ./a.out 
We got a 805423f
 clang -g -Wall -O2 test.c
 ./a.out 
We got a b768d9d6
 clang -g -Wall -O3 test.c
 ./a.out 
We got a b76899d6
```

(The example is quite unstable and for example by putting a printf inside foo, gcc always prints "We got a beaf". Clang.. not..)

The above example is just my way to try and be clear.

My REAL question (and my goal) is the following: 
How can a extract the original address of arg_a, i.e. the address that the caller (main) pushed 0xbe00 in the stack by using CLANG from inside foo function? (gcc is not an option, although it's still interesting)

Thanx for your time!

edit: made foo variadic in order for the question to make more sense...

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to smash the stack.  (Tsk tsk.)  You've made some assumptions that aren't going to hold up as a general case.  Just off the top of my head some bad assumptions: order of the stack, that there even IS a stack [compilers can register pass values if they want to], and presence of known values in that memory for debugging/overflow detection.

Comment: You are right clint! And since the code is going to be compiled with toolchain for MIPS (that generally passes the first 4 arguments in registers $4-$7), things look even more difficult...
Please see the edit that I made..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work for you.

First off, if gcc is your compiler, why don't you just pull in the standard C library? If you don't want to do that, what about pulling in just stdarg.h from the standard implementation?

The version of stdarg.h I'm looking at (came with gcc 4.4.0 on Windows) is basically a bunch of macros that call compiler builtins - if you've got the right one for the compiler, then it should be easy, even if you don't use the rest of the standard library (I can understand a reluctance to pull in that whole mess).

If that doesn't work for you, then try marking the function you are writing as variadic, and look in the compiler docs for how it builds the stack. You may well have to write some snippets of assembler depending on platform, but by declaring the function as variadic you'll force the compiler to build the stack in a predictable way.

If your compiler doesn't support variadic arguments to functions, then you might want to reconsider your other options.

Comment: Michael you were very helpful! Indeed, stdarg.h is a set of macros to __builtin_ functions and are more or less the same for gcc and llvm/clang (I'm using the second one). So I ended up implementing variadic functions the "right" way, (although the "wrong" way is still more interesting!)

Answer (score 4):

In short, don't do that.

What you're doing is undefined behavior.  If you want the address of `arg_b`, then write `&arg_b`.  Trying to get it by using pointery trickery with `arg_a` will not work because of C's aliasing rules.  The compiler assumes that certain pointers won't alias each other, so the optimizer makes assumptions which are no longer true when you do that.  As a result, the code functions improperly.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Adam!
The reason I want to do that is because I want to build a variadic function (printf actually) for an embedded device that doesn't have <stdarg.h>. So writing &arg_b is not an option...

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing results in undefined behavior.

The proper way of accessing optional arguments (from `...`) is to use the `va_list`, `va_start()`, `va_arg()` and `va_end()` macros from `<stdarg.h>`.

Examples of using these macros are numerous and you can find them online easily.

Guesswork is not allowed here.